# How to 301 redirect with or without the trailing slash?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect
`site.com/login` OR `site.com/login/`
to `site.com/wp-login.php`

Here's what I have so far:

```
RewriteRule ^login$ "\/wp\-login\.php" [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't redirect /login/ (with the trailing slash). How to tell htaccess to redirect with or without the trailing slash?

Thank you,
Cris

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You want the expression to see the `/` as optional

```
^login/?$
```

The `?`  token will allow for the zero or one occurence of the `/`