# Mod_rewrite, 301s and slashes

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I want to set up a pretty url on a virtual directory. But I also want a safety net for the virtual directory just in case anyone hits that directly. Let's call the virtual directory foo

```
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ ./foo/page.php?term=$1 [QSA]
```

This seems to be working fine. All pages are re-directing and displaying correctly and the pretty URL is remaining in the address bar (rather than re-directing to the physical address as with a 301)

But if I go to www.domain.com/foo I get a 404 :(

If I go to www.domain.com/foo/ (note the slash) then the script continues and an error message is displayed thanks to some extra validation in my PHP.

How can I tidy up the virtual directory (with/without a slash)? No one should ever hit that but if they do I want to be ready and re-direct them to the homepage.

After reading [another users question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983726/how-to-301-redirect-with-or-without-the-trailing-slash) I tried:

```
Redirect 301 /foo /?q=empty
```

But this is conflicting with my initial rule. I'm ending up with links like:
www.domain.com/?q=empty/Blah (instead of /foo/Blah)

Comment: provide details: on how your pretty URL looks like for `topic`.

Comment: topic was supposed to be foo. edited.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^foo/$ 
RewriteRule ^  /foo/page.php?q=empty [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ foo/page.php?term=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Making the slash optional could cause problems with folders starting with `foo`. e.g. `/foobar/test` would redirect to `/foo/page.php?term=bar/test`. Not a problem in this case because of the rule above it, which makes it kind of useless.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an extra rule for this case

```
RewriteRule ^foo/?$ ./foo/page.php [QSA, L]
```